# Windows 10 Docker - Entrypoint not found

Tags: linux, windows, docker, devops

On my work there is a docker project with all backend setup.
The code of dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9.6-alpine

# Установка локальных переменных
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/freedom
WORKDIR /usr/src/freedom

# Установка зависимостей для Django
RUN apk update \
    && apk add postgresql \
    && apk add postgresql-dev \
    && apk add gcc libc-dev make git libffi-dev openssl-dev python3-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev \
    && apk add jpeg-dev zlib-dev libjpeg libffi-dev
#     && pip install Pillow \
#     && apk del build-deps

# ENV LANG C.UTF-8
# ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8

CMD python3 --version
CMD . env/bin/activate
COPY ./requirements.txt ./requirements.txt

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

# run entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/freedom/entrypoint.sh"]
```

When running the project with `docker-compose up --build` (right after clonning, no shenanigans) on Linux everything works fine. It finds its entrypoint.sh fine) its okay. When running from windows entrypoint dont run.

- Running entrypoint from a global path like "C:/abc/abc/.."

Please help

I tried:

- Removing ENTRYPOINT and running it as CMD
- Adding entry point to /usr/src/freedom on my C: folder
- Changing paths

Comment: Your container is Alpine, not Windows. When you use an entrypoint the path you give is from inside the machine

Comment: Why would you change a path in your linux-based container to a windows-like path?

Comment: @deprirscher I really dont know man, I never worked with linux :P Can you help me to set it up?

Comment: @PedroRodrigues Hey, what do I need to do right now to fix it? This path works on my ubuntu vm

Comment: @ColdDarkness Are you sure you need to change anything? The machine you are using shouldn't really matter. Also, having more than one CMD instruction is useless, you can only use one, which will be the latest one (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)

Comment: @PedroRodrigues it doesnt work. entrypoint.sh isnt found like that and I don't know why

Comment: Where is that file located? Is it where you executed `docker-compose up --build`? Like, if you use `ls` in the same place you execute that command, does it have the `entrypoint.sh`file?

Comment: @PedroRodrigues https://imgur.com/a/pKjQ7n0

Comment: Hmm... What does it show if you use `RUN ls -la` between the `COPY` and `ENTRYPOINT` instructions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251303/discussion-between-pedro-rodrigues-and-colddarkness).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option you have is to call the shell and execute the file, as if: `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "sh /usr/src/freedom/entrypoint.sh"]`

But in the end I think the best solution will be to simply use a single `CMD` instruction, like: `CMD ["/usr/src/freedom/entrypoint.sh"]` (with this I mean you should remove all the `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` instructions you currently have and use this one.)

You can check the difference between `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` in the documentation and this SoF post:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact
- [What is the difference between CMD and ENTRYPOINT in a Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile)

Also, as stated in the documentation, [having two CMD commands is useless](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) since the latest one is the one that will be applied.